# How do i traverse through multidimensional array in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, laravel-5

I am trying to get the data from multiple tables for the table structure given below

[image]

Content for the tables are

[image]

In above scenario I just want to fetch the array of unique movie_id for the city_id=1 and my code is given below

```
 $movies=General_cities::with('cinemahall.showtime')->where('city_id',$selectedcity->city_id)->get();

 return $movies[0]['cinemahall'][1]['showtime'][0]['movie_id'];
```

where $selectedcity->city_id is "1", I am getting all the data in bunch from above code. I am also able to display single movie_id , but i want to traverse from all the multidimentional array and collect the all unique movie_id.

kindly help me as this seems to be quite difficult to do.
in above scenario i should get the movie_id array as [1,2].

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function in your model

```
public function unique_movie_id()
{

return $this->join('movies_cinemahall', 'movies_cinemahall.city_id','=','general_cities.id')->join('movies_showtime', 'movies_showtime.cinema_id','=','movies_cinemahall.cinema_id')->join('movies','movies.movie_id','=','movies_showtime.movie_id')->distinct('movies.movie_id')->select('movies.id')->get();

}
```